# How to move cursor while clicking the touchpad?

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 and I really dislike the touchpad behavior.

For example when I try to move a file I'm used to do it by clicking on the file with one finger and moving it with another. So the first time I wanted to move something in Ubuntu I tried the same thing. I clicked the file with my index finger and tried to move it with my middle finger. Sadly it doesn't work. Ubuntu doesn't recognize my second finger whilst I'm clicking with the first finger. So I have to use the finger I'm clicking with to move the file.

In my opinion that's really annoying because the touchpad isn't that big and when I need to move a file for a long way I can't do that.

Does anyone know if I can change that behavior? I have a 13' Alienware Notebook and the synaptics driver installed.

Comment: Double tap to select and move the finger. This way you don't need any click

Comment: My touchpad doesn't recognize that as a click and I'm pretty sure that it wouldn't help cause i can't move the cursor with a second finger when another is on the touchpad as well

Comment: no, that's for drag-and-drop in synaptics and I've used it for resizing/moving windows or moving files for years

Comment: But when I for example double tap a file nothing happens.. I've to click to make my touchpad realize it. Do I have to configure something to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I am replacing the left mouse button of my touchpad (often does not work) with one keyboard shortcut to each press and release the left mouse.

The commands are `xdotool mousedown 1` and `xdotool mouseup 1`
(you first have to install it with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`).

Then I set custom shortcuts for both actions (for me: [Ctrl]+[Menu] = left mouse button down; [Shift]+[Menu] = left mouse button up) in *System settings* panel > *Keyboard* > Tab *shortcuts*.

Now I move my mouse pointer over the object I want to grab, press [Ctrl]+[Menu] to push the left mouse button down, move the pointer and the grabbed object with the touchpad and finally press [Shift]+[Menu] to release the left mouse button and drop the object at its new position.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but is there no other way to fix that? I think it could be really annoying to always use the keyboard not just to copy things but for marking stuff and so on :(

Comment: I totally agree with you, and therefore I always use a USB mouse, if possible. I am looking forward to a better solution, too... :-)

Comment: Okay hopefully there is a better solution otherwise I've to buy a small wireless mouse.. don't like the whole cable stuff :D.. Thanks anyways :)